# I want to find the long form from the short form from the given string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a sentence where I need to extract the last oocurance of the matching string

https://regex101.com/r/CRR5zi/2

That is in the above example the expression only needs to select the last occurance and not the first one **"Universal Serial Bus"**

```
U.* S.* B.*
```

*used to enable all types of communication services on the Universal Serial Bus is an example here*

I have tried with

Comment: What is the point of selecting the last occurrence?  What do you plan on doing with this match?

Comment: it must mach the abbreviation USB, if not it selects all text as shown here regex101.com/r/CRR5zi/2

Comment: Your regex should use `B\w+\b` instead of `.* ` - if USB is last in sentence it fails.

Comment: also it will abbreviate something like `User Service Boundary` to `USB`. Is that correct behavior?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/CRR5zi/3 but this doesnt selected the Universal Serial Bus

Comment: Check here: https://regex101.com/r/CRR5zi/4

Comment: U\w+ S\w+ B\w+ is also correct. @Justinas you are right, please post as answer

Comment: The last occurrence could be like this `^.*\b(U\w+ S\w+ B\w+)`  https://regex101.com/r/jiQwqU/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting any character that follows `U`, `S` or `B`.

Change your regex to less greedy (and possible remove `/i` flag to select only upper-case letters)

```regex
(U\w+ S\w+ B\w+)
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/UZ5RVn/2)

Answer (score 1):

Just match them all (globally) and take the last match from the result.

```
const your_regex_pattern = /U.*?S.*?B.*?(?=\s|$)/g;
```

Is that what you need? (Note the case insensitivity has been removed, otherwise you have to avoid matching "anything" with ".", instead only match non-whitespaces) like:

```
const your_insensitive_regex_pattern = /U[\S]*?\s*S[\S]*?\s*B[\S]*?(?=\s|$)/gmi;
```